# Paragraph inside div word wrap

Tags: css

I'm echo-ing the following html code:

```
echo "<p><b>" . $newId['username'] . "</b><br>" . $data['content'] . "</p>";
```

This `$data['content']` can sometimes be very long so I'm trying to make word-wrap but it is not working. I tried `word-break: break-all` but with no change.

So basically this is how my html looks like:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<p><b>Some username</b><br>Some very long text</p>
</div>

#myDiv p{

font-size: 80%;
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 690px;
}
```

I need your help

Comment: Did you try `white-space: normal`?

Comment: I don't see how that wouldn't work. Can you provide an example..?

Comment: [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/mxhy2/). Maybe your text isn't long enough to wrap.

Comment: @showdev I guess the OP wants it to wrap to the window, as you initially said.

Comment: Actually it is working, it seems I had inheriteded white-space: nowrap from parent div. Well, thanks for helping @Chad